# Initialize the length of a buffer array with a variable

Tags: c++, c

I am reading buffer bytes from a socket but I don't know how to initialize the buffer array with the length info.

```
uint32_t len;
int lengthbytes = 0;
int databytes = 0;

// receive the length info of an image data
lengthbytes = recv(clientSocket, (char *)&len, sizeof(len), 0);

// convert hexadecimal data to length in bytes
len = ntohl(len);

// ????? how to initialize the buffer array with the length info ????
char buf[len];   -----> this is illegal in C  

// read the image data 
databytes = recv(clientSocket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare `buf` you declare a *variable length array*. This is legal in C (from the C99 standard) but illegal in C++. In C++ you can instead use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<char> buf(len);
```

You can use this vector in the call to `recv` as well:

```
databytes = recv(clientSocket, &buf[0], buf.size(), 0);
```

---

To use the vector inside a loop, you have two choices:

1. Declare the variable outside the loop, and use [`clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) and [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) when needed:

   ```
   std::vector<char> buf;

   // ...

   for (int i = 0; i < number_of_images; i++)
   {
       std::cout << "Fetching image #" << (i + 1) << '\n';

       // Get the image length
       size_t length = get_image_length();

       buf.clear();  // Clear the buffer
       buf.resize(length);  // Set the size to the image length

       // Receive the image
       databytes = recv(clientSocket, &buf[0], buf.size(), 0);
   }
   ```
2. Declare the vector to be local inside the loop:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < number_of_images; i++)
   {
       std::cout << "Fetching image #" << (i + 1) << '\n';

       // Get the image length
       size_t length = get_image_length();

       std::vector<char> buf(length);

       // Receive the image
       databytes = recv(clientSocket, &buf[0], buf.size(), 0);
   }
   ```

Comment: if I want to use while loop to receive many images, how do I delete the content of `buf` at the end of each loop?

Answer (score 4):

```
len = ntohl(len);
char buf[len];  //----> this is illegal in C
```

This is valid in C99 and it is called a *variable length array*. If you are not using C99 use `malloc` to allocate the array (and declare `buf` as a `char *`).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dynamic memory allocation;

```
char* buf = new char[len];
```

If you're done using `buf`, don't forget to call `delete` to free the memory.

```
delete[] buf;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please allocate the buffer through `malloc` i.e. `buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * len);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with new or malloc. 
Don't forget to delete the buffer when done!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `std::vector<char>`, and then use it's `data()` as an array buffer:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<char> buf(len);
databytes = recv(clientSocket, buf.data(), buf.size(), 0); // access underlying char array
databytes = recv(clientSocket, &buf[0], buf.size(), 0);    // as above, C++03 version
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a class called `tempbuf` precisely for this purpose in C++.

You can find it here:
[small_lib.cpp](https://github.com/ruben2020/codequery/blob/master/querylib/small_lib.cpp)
[small_lib.h](https://github.com/ruben2020/codequery/blob/master/querylib/small_lib.h)

These two files are MIT-licensed, so you can use it anyway you like.

How to use this class?

```
tempbuf buf(len);
databytes = recv(clientSocket, buf.get(), buf.size(), 0); // if you want char* returned
databytes = recv(clientSocket, buf.constchar(), buf.size(), 0); // if you want constchar* returned
```

And guess why I wrote this class? You don't need to delete or deallocate the dynamically allocated memory because it is done in the destructor of the class.

Why didn't I use `std::auto_ptr`? Because from my understanding, that's only for non-arrays as in it supports `new X` but not `new X[10]`.